# Gitリポジトリの更新を自動で複数のクライアントPCに反映させたい

Tags: git, windows-10

Git管理しているソースコードの更新を、NAS上のリポジトリにpushしたら、それをトリガに自動でネットワークに接続されている各PCにpushするという方式で自動デプロイ的な事を行いたいと考えているのですが、Windows 10のPCでその様な事を実現する方法が有りましたらどなたかご教示頂けないでしょうか？
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

[2019/02/16追記]なお、以下の様な制約・前提条件があります。

(1)外部ネットワークとの直接の接続不可
GitHubの様な外部のサービスはセキュリティ上の問題で、利用できない事になっており、pushする際は、PCを持参して、有線で接続して手動でpushする必要があります。同じ理由でWebサーバを立てるのもむづかしい状況です。

(2)ローカルレポジトリはユーザが利用
ローカルレポジトリにpushしたソフトはユーザ利用向けの為、それぞれのPCでGitの細かい運用を指示するのは出来ない状況です。

(3)メインレポジトリとローカルレポジトリ間の接続はLAN内のネットワーク経由で通信できます。

Comment: ローカルリポジトリへの展開とはいわゆる、CI（自動ビルドや自動デプロイ）を想定していますか？それとも単純に全員に常に最新のソースを触ってほしいから「必ず最新のpullする」という運用が難しいからですか？

Comment: 後者の「全員に常に最新のソースを触って欲しい」為の簡易的な方法を検討しています。「必ず最新のpullする」という運用を、開発担当でない方のPCに配信出来さえすればそれで良いと思います。

Comment: 開発担当でない方のPCには常に起動していますか？誰かがプッシュ時にPCが起動していないときはどうなりますか？

Comment: 開発担当でない方のPCは、常に起動している状況を想定しています。まずは数台程度のPCが対象なので、停電などの特別な状況でpush出来ないのであれば、手動で対応しようと考えています。

Comment: 各ローカルリポジトリへの同期はGitを使う必要はありますか？

Comment: はい、Git管理してる為同期もGitを使いたいと考えております。

Comment: **NASのメインリポジトリ**はどんな構成なのでしょうか？(gitサーバとしては何で管理している？) / GitHub等であれば**hook**の仕組みを使えばpushをトリガーにコマンド実行(URLを叩いたり)できそうですが、いずれにせよPC1～3は何かしらの方法でサーバとして振る舞う必要がありそうな気がします。

Comment: NAS上のフォルダ内にgit管理しているレポジトリをクローンした物を基に随時実装したコードをpushしています。特にサーバを立てて居ないので、何かしら構成を変える必要がありそうですね。

Comment: トリガなど使わず、以下のQiitaの記事の様にして全てのPC上のリポジトリに同時pushするのが良い気がしてきました:
[複数のリポジトリに同時pushする](https://qiita.com/_am_/items/d57cbcc9383cf4b16cad)

Comment: 質問者様はpushとpullがちょっと混同していそうですね。クローンしたGitの場合はメインリポジトリから持ってくる場合はpullになります。今回やりたいのはクローンしたローカルリポジトリでpullですよね？

Comment: 「開発担当ではないPC」に「常に最新のデータを参照させたい」であるなら、Gitにこだわらず対象データをNAS経由で参照させるのが一番手っ取り早い気がします (編集が必要無ければ安全のため"読み取り専用"で)。 / 繰り返しになりますが、`push`するには相手先(各PC)が何かしらの方法でサーバとなる必要があると思います。

Comment: @keitaro_so 元々NASのメインレポジトリは開発していたレポジトリからクローンしたものを配置しました。やりたいのは、そこにコードを修正したコミットをpushした場合にメインレポジトリと同時にソフトの使用者が利用するローカルPCに配備する事です。

Comment: @cubick 開発しているソースコードの管理にGitを使っているのは変えられないのと、極力サーバは建てずに変更をアップデートするのだけ簡単に行いたいので、現状では、各ローカルPCを[1]に記載の方法で参照できる様にして、[2]の方法で登録して一斉にpushするのが良さそうだと思えてきました。

[1][ローカルのフォルダをgitのremoteとして設定したい(windows)](https://qiita.com/KTakata/items/baa96574ce391775a212)
[2][複数のリポジトリに同時pushする](https://qiita.com/_am_/items/d57cbcc9383cf4b16cad)

Comment: 補足すると、諸事情によりGitHubなどを経由でネットワーク経由でデプロイできず、更新がある時はその都度実機のある場所に行き、コードで接続して変更をpushする必要があります。

Answer (score 4):

`git-push`はデプロイ用途には向いていません。別の方式を検討すべきだと考えます。

---

本質問は[XY問題](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2702/2808)あるいは[ハンマー釘病](https://www.google.com/search?q=%E3%83%8F%E3%83%B3%E3%83%9E%E3%83%BC%E9%87%98%E7%97%85)であると感じました。

---

`git-push` コマンド自身に対する誤解があると思います。

[git push](https://git-scm.com/book/ja/v2/Appendix-C%3A-Git%E3%81%AE%E3%82%B3%E3%83%9E%E3%83%B3%E3%83%89-%E3%83%97%E3%83%AD%E3%82%B8%E3%82%A7%E3%82%AF%E3%83%88%E3%81%AE%E5%85%B1%E6%9C%89%E3%81%A8%E3%82%A2%E3%83%83%E3%83%97%E3%83%87%E3%83%BC%E3%83%88#_git_push):

> git push コマンドは、他のリポジトリと通信し、自分のローカル・データベースにあって通信先のリポジトリにないものは何かを計算した上で、差分を通信先のリポジトリへプッシュします。このコマンドは、通信先のリポジトリへの書き込みアクセスを必要とするので、通常は何らかの形で認証が行われます。

- ([想定](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/52786/git%e3%83%aa%e3%83%9d%e3%82%b8%e3%83%88%e3%83%aa%e3%81%ae%e8%87%aa%e5%8b%95%e6%9b%b4%e6%96%b0%e3%81%ab%e3%81%a4%e3%81%84%e3%81%a6#comment55207_52786)通り動作したとして) `git-push` を実行したとき更新されるのはPC1,2,3のGitリポジトリであり、ソースコード(作業ディレクトリにcheckoutしているバージョン管理対象のファイル)ではありません。

  - 作業ディレクトリのファイルを更新するには`git-checkout`が必要です。
- 図中の①を行ったユーザがPC1,2,3へ書き込むための認証の仕組みが必要です。

  - 例えば[SSHプロトコル](https://git-scm.com/book/ja/v2/Git%E3%82%B5%E3%83%BC%E3%83%90%E3%83%BC-%E3%83%97%E3%83%AD%E3%83%88%E3%82%B3%E3%83%AB#_ssh_%E3%83%97%E3%83%AD%E3%83%88%E3%82%B3%E3%83%AB)を利用するならPC1,2,3にSSHサーバを立てる必要があります。

その他思いついたこととしては:

- PC4,5,6...とユーザが増えるごとにリモートリポジトリ設定の追加、認証サーバのセットアップが必要になるので管理面倒です。

---

質問文に書かれている以外の条件が無いのであれば、NASに共有ディレクトリを設定してそれをPC1,2,3それぞれでマウントするのが簡単ではないでしょうか。
共有ディレクトリに置くファイルを更新する手段として[Gitフック](https://git-scm.com/book/ja/v2/Git-%E3%81%AE%E3%82%AB%E3%82%B9%E3%82%BF%E3%83%9E%E3%82%A4%E3%82%BA-Git-%E3%83%95%E3%83%83%E3%82%AF#_code_post_receive_code)が利用できると思います。

Comment: 条件としては、質問文で述べて居なかったのですが、NAS上の共有ディレクトリを各PCから参照する方式(マウントに相当？）を今まで利用していたのですが、通信速度の関係でローカル上にアップして欲しいという要望があり、今回質問させて頂きました。共有ディレクトリ上のレポジトリは、直接ネットワークに接続できないため、PCを持参して有線接続した上でpushして新たな更新を加えておりました。Gitフックはあまり詳しく無かったのですが、確かに利用できそうです。

Comment: @nobelnambu 質問は後からでも [編集] できますので、回答の前提条件となるような情報は(元質問に付いたコメントも含めて)ぜひ**質問自体に追記**してください。 / 質問文が編集された方が一覧のトップに再表示されるので回答者の目に止まりやすくなります。

Comment: @cubick  そうですね。もう少し情報をこちらで整理して質問文にまとめてみます。